# Summing values with a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.x, sum

Instructions:

Deﬁne a function called summer() that sums the elements in a list of numbers.
summer() takes a single list argument. First you need to initialize an accumulator to zero, then use a for-loop to add the value of each element in the list, and ﬁnally return the total sum to the calling program.

Question:

I know how to do this very easily with the sum() function but I am not allowed to use this. I must find a way to sum a lists value and print that sum.

i.e

```
>>> x = [9, 3, 21, 15]
>>> summer(x)
48
```

What I've tried:

```
xlist=[9,3,21,15]
sumed=0
def summer(x):
    for i in x:    
    sumed+=i

print(sumed)


summer(xlist)
```

I keep getting 'sumed' ref. before assignment with this one

Comment: Have you tried anything? Did you read the part of your class materials that explained how a `for` loop works?

Comment: @balki I edited the original to what I have tried using

Answer (score 1):

Let me translate the instructions step by step:

- Step1

> Deﬁne a function called summer() that sums the elements in a list of
>   numbers.

```
def summer():
  "This function sums the elements in a list"
```

- Step2

> summer() takes a single list argument.

```
def summer(a_list):
  "This function sums the elements in a list"
```

- Step3

> First you need to initialize an accumulator to zero

```
def summer(a_list):
  "This function sums the elements in a list"
  accumulator = 0
```

- Step4

> , then use a for-loop to add the value of each element in the list,

```
def summer(a_list):
  "This function sums the elements in a list"
  accumulator = 0
  for elem in a_list:
    accumulator+= elem
```

> and ﬁnally return the total sum to the calling program.

```
def summer(a_list):
  "This function sums the elements in a list"
  accumulator = 0
  for elem in a_list:
    accumulator+= elem
  return accumulator
```

Now, you can try in the shell:

```
>>> def summer(a_list):
...   "This function sums the elements in a list"
...   accumulator = 0
...   for elem in a_list:
...     accumulator+= elem
...   return accumulator
...
>>> x = [9, 3, 21, 15]
>>> summer(x)
48
```